# How do you manage protocol buffer definition files?

Tags: protocol-buffers, project-organization

At my company, we've standardized on using Protocol Buffers over a message bus as a way to allow services to communicate.

This is fine, however I'm running into a problem in trying to figure out how to structure common definition files that I'd like to share amongst different teams. Is there a commonly accepted way to make collections of protocol buffer definitions available across teams?

Also, is it just a fact of life that all import headers have to refer to the directory in which the protocol buffer compiler executes? Frankly this seems a little silly since the protocol buffers allow for namespace definitions. Or is this just an artifact of the Java centric origins of Protocol Buffers?

Answer (score 0):

I can only answer part of the question:

Also, is it just a fact of life that all import headers have to refer to the directory in which the protocol buffer compiler executes?

you can use **--proto_path=** option to specify where *.proto's exist + all the imbedded proto's